# I wish to install Kubuntu 20.04.1 in dual boot with the already installed Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, kubuntu

Here is my actual installation:

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1 ext4 /boot     
/dev/sda2 ext4 /         ubuntu 18.04.3
/dev/sda3 ext4 /home
/dev/sda4 ext4 /         Kubuntu 20.04.1
```

When installing Kubuntu, I assigned the boot to Kubuntu, but it doesn't have any effect: it boots on Ubuntu and doesn't see Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can install any OS in dual boot, obviously to boot on it, that would require a bootloader entry on the computer boot menu (ie, when you press F8)

Using Gparted on a live usb (because mounted partitions like "/" cannot be moved if needed) I would build partitions prior to install.
Then during the install process, select `MANUAL partitioning` and map `sdaX` as `ext4` to mount `/` AND select your **EFI** partition as `efi partition` (usually it is partition 1 or 2 - everything else is optionnal)

Normally Grub2 should be installed as default on Ubuntu, that would guarantees that ubuntu pops when pressiong the boot select key during computer's POST (usually F8 or F9 or even F11 key)

What you may encounter with Kubuntu has the label `ubuntu` in boot menu; You can totally edit this.
Your issue seems to be related to a missing EFI partition mount setup during kubuntu installation.

You can check your partitions with according **mount points** with `sudo fdisk -l` and `lsblk`
example on a nvme0n1 instead of sda:

```
NAME                       MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1                    259:0    0 447,1G  0 disk   
├─nvme0n1p1                259:1    0   529M  0 part   
├─nvme0n1p2                259:2    0   100M  0 part   /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p3                259:3    0    16M  0 part   
├─nvme0n1p4                259:4    0 342,5G  0 part   
├─nvme0n1p5                259:5    0   100G  0 part   /
└─nvme0n1p6                259:6    0     4G  0 part   [SWAP]
```

Technically when you cannot boot but it is installed somewhere, you would have to boot on a live-usb then mount the drive and check what's wrong then fix it with [`fstab`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab)